# Storing PHP output issued by crontab

Tags: cron, debugging

I have a PHP file that is suppose to send one email per day scheduled by crontab. Here is my crontab:

```
45 23 * * * php /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dailyStaffReport.php
```

I noticed that it's not working, that is, the email is not being sent. So I tried the following:

```
00 11 * * * php /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dailyStaffReport.php 
            >> /var/log/crontab.linus.log 2>&1
```

*Note: the time schedule here is not important, I'm constantly changing it for the testing purpose*

That did not work. The file `crontab.linus.log` was not created.

While checking the `/var/log/cron` file, I noticed that my cron is executed

```
Feb 25 11:22:01 shoutcast01 CROND[3395]: (apache) CMD (php 
    /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dailyStaffReport.php 
    >> /var/log/crontab.linus.log 2>&1)
```

And lastly, if I manually execute `php /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dailyStaffReport.php` I get the email right away in my inbox. I even wrote some `echoes` in the PHP script in the hopes to try and see if somewhere along the line the script fails.

```
[root@shoutcast01 ~]# php /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dailyStaffReport.php
  LOADING STAFF USERS...
  COMPUTING STAFF WORK TIME...
  BUILDING CHART...
  SAVING CHART...
  WRITING DOWN THE CHART...
  SENDING THE EMAIL...
  1
  DONE.
```

On a simular matter, I have another file that is scheduled to send emails every 2 minutes and it works perfectly.

```
[root@shoutcast01 ~]# crontab -u apache -l
22 11 * * * php /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dailyStaffReport.php 
      >> /var/log/crontab.linus.log 2>&1
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/html/linus/class/runnable/dispatchEmail.php
```

### To sum up

- The email gets delivered if I execute the script manually in the terminal.
- the email does not gets delivered, but cron log tells me the script was executed.
- I'm unable to log anything with `>> /var/log/crontab.linus.log 2>&1`

Any tips on what I can do to try and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that debugging wasn't working was that I was trying to store the debug information into `/var/log/crontab.linus.log` and that file didn't exist and the user `apache` did not have permission to create it.

After realizing that, I created the file myself

```
touch crontab.linus.log
chown apache crontab.linus.log
chgrp apache crontab.linus.log
chmod 0777 crontab.linus.log
```

Then I scheduled the task again and waited for it to be executed. Turns out, the original problem was also about permission.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to
>   write the file [...]

So I set `chmod 0777` in the foloder that the PHP script saves it's images. After that the schedule being executed by apache user was successfully executed and the email was sent.